# How often do politicians pay extras to act the part of cheering crowds?

Tags: united-states, media, campaigning

*The Hollywood Reporter* (6/17/15) noted that [a politician's campaign paid a crowd of extras $50 a head to cheer him during a campaign event](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/donald-trump-campaign-offered-actors-803161).

- How often are [acting extras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extra_(acting)) employed by politicians in such a fashion?
- During the last 10 years in the USA, how much has been spent on political campaign extra hires?  (Even a ballpark estimate would be of interest.)

Comment: The technical term is [*claque*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claque)

Comment: @SJuan76, Thanks, the term *claque* would seem to fill a useful gap, but isn't so much *technical* as historic and specific to French theatre, with perhaps *one* speculative [recent usage](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/monkey-cage/wp/2017/01/23/this-is-how-donald-trump-engineers-applause/) by *Hentry Farrell* of the *Washington Post*.

Comment: It has been done (e.g. in 2016). It is quite rare in the U.S. I'd be surprised if it happens more than a few dozen times in the last ten years.

Answer (score 7):

In 2015 [*The Atlantic Monthly* reported](https://www.theatlantic.com/business/archive/2015/07/crowd-hiring-politics-campaign-2016/399002/) that the hiring of political crowds, (generally in cities with a surplus of would-be actors), is enough of a thing to support several businesses that are open about the practice:

1. *Crowds on Demand*

   > A foreign government hired Crowds on Demand to help generate a
   >   positive reception for its newly elected leader during the UN General
   >   Assembly. The concern was ensuring that the leader was well received
   >   by a US audience and confident for his work at the UN. We created
   >   demonstrations of support with diverse crowds. We also used the media
   >   primarily local and national outlets to bring more attention to these
   >   demonstrations which led to a mostly positive portrayal. The crowds
   >   that we deployed drew in more supporters creating a strong presence
   >   for this leader at the UN and an improved perception of him by the
   >   American public.
   >      -- [PROTESTS AND RALLIES, *Crowds on Demand* website](https://crowdsondemand.com/political-services/)
2. *Crowds for Rent*

   > Political/Corporate Manpower
   >
   > These packages are created specifically for any professional organization (large corporations to small businesses), political campaigns, or any organization that needs on demand manpower to support their commercial or political objectives. We can help with the opening of a new restaurant, night club, retail store, special event, press conference or any other type of event that requires people to fill seats, lines, ask questions or write reviews to greatly enhance the profile of any business. Every business should be able to guarantee that the grand opening or a special event is a success with being reassured that people will attend. We also provide manpower for protests, rallys, campaigns, ballot measures or any other event that requires a large group of people supporting a specific cause. No event is too big or too small - we service everyone from local campaigns to national political efforts.
   >   --[Crowds for Rent Services, *Crowds for Rent* website](http://www.crowdsforrent.com/services.html)
3. *Gotham Government Relations*

   Not quite as open:

   > Gotham recognizes the inherent power found in an effectively run and targeted grassroots campaign. Employing door to door lobbying and promoting community support through consensus building, our firm will employ the most advanced strategies that have been proven successful in influencing public policy.
   >   --[Gotham Government Relations, Grassroots Campaigns website](http://gothamgr.com/grassroots-campaigns/)

   *Gotham Government Relations* is too indirect to say they hire crowds, rather they *organize rallies*.  In [2013 Salon reported](http://www.salon.com/2013/04/14/i_was_a_political_astroturfer/) that *GGR* recruits extras for rallies from *Craigslist*, and the company's parent law firm sent email to those extras exhorting them to dissimulate:

   > This client pays $20 an hour for a little less than an hour. All you really have to do is show up and support our rally. We ask that you DO NOT under any circumstances talk to the press or media on our behalf or discuss anything about your attendance or compensation with them.

...plus several other agencies provide similar services, that seem to be less public about it.

As of yet I've run into no numbers showing the monetary scale of these businesses, but wages are variable.  It ranges from [*$50/head* noted in the OP](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/donald-trump-campaign-offered-actors-803161), to *Gotham Government Relations* rate of *$20/hour* noted above, and *The Atlantic Monthly* article cited [*$15/hour* for attending events for a (failed) NYC Mayoral bid](http://nypost.com/2013/08/28/weiner-paid-for-phony-supporters-at-campaign-events-source-says/).